# Android scrollview hiding top content in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-scrollview

Im having a problem where the android scrollview starts hiding a pair of textviews I have at the top of my layout, I have found another person on this very site who had that problem and was able to get help unfortunately the person who helped them didnt actually say what fixes it, can anyone tell me what was the fix here?

[android scrollview hiding top content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302912/android-scrollview-hiding-top-content)

any help would be huge here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/title_color_dark_transparent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saysomething"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/loading"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saysomethinginfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/loading"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tweetedittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
            android:lines="3"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/photobutton"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:onClick="photobuttonClicked"
                android:text="@string/photobuttontext"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/charactersremaining"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/posttweetbutton"
                android:text="@string/characters"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@id/posttweetbutton"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:onClick="posttweetbuttonClicked"
                android:text="@string/postbuttonstext"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photodetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I fail to see any TextViews above your ScrollView. You're also missing your closing tag on your ScrollView.

Comment: seems like I mistakenly didnt comment in the closing tag for the scrollview but its there now, the textviews are the first ones that you see inside the linear layout, placing the textviews outside the linear layout gives me an error because apparently you cant have more than one child in the scrollview

Comment: I thought you don't want your ScrollView to hide those TextViews? Maybe you should explain what you actually want the layout to look like, because it's not very clear to me.

Comment: the layout is too big for the screen, so I put it in a scrollview, but when I set the image in the imageview the 2 textviews "@+id/saysomething" and "@+id/saysomethinginfo" are hidden and cant be scrolled to see what it says, what I need is for the user to be able to scroll up and be able to see whats hidden under there

Comment: Might this be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280051/black-screen-using-scrollview-relativelayout-and-a-costum-view-acting-like-a/9095958#9095958

Comment: unfortunately this also did not help :/

Comment: You code works fine its showing text. Can u please take screen shot of your layout and posted it?since it help us to understand what you needed..

Comment: I figured out the problem, turns out nothing was actually wrong but when the emulator launches the screen with the scrollview they actually simulate the keyboard being activated which causes the top elements to be hidden the way that it was, I was able to figure this out by testing the app on an actual device, so thankfully impact seems to be averted hopefully this helps any one else who has this perceived problem lol

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Found it ! 
It's the `android:layout_gravity="center"` in the `LinearLayout` that is the culprit. Just delete this and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for this - worked for me in an instance of this problem.

Comment: Works, and if you still need to center the View inside use this workaround: http://pivotallabs.com/centering-a-view-within-a-scrollview/

Comment: Big thank you @Sylphe, strange that your answer not accepted :(

Comment: Many thanks for this. I had a similar problem but in a `HorizontalScrollView`. Shouldn't this be filed as a bug on Google Code? At the very least, lint should be added to warn of this perhaps.

Comment: removing 'android:layout_gravity="center"' is helped for me! Thanks guy! :))))))))))))

Comment: I had this issue, but I needed to move many of the layout parameters that I used to have on the top level linearlayout to the now top level scrollview.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried setting

android:fillViewport="true"

in the ScrollView?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:background="@color/title_color_dark_transparent" >
```

Answer (score 2):

You can scroll programmatically.

1. Remove android:layout_gravity property from xml
2. Add scrolling to onResume function

Some code from my project:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final HorizontalScrollView svInMenu = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svInMenu);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = svInMenu.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            svInMenu.scrollTo(svInMenu.getRight() / 4, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `LinearLayout` has its height set to `match_parent`. It should be `wrap_content` instead. The inner `LinearLayout` should also have height `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_weight="1" to your scrollview. It will resolve the problem. Something like this

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
```