# Stop softkey from pushing toolbar above screen

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-softkeyboard

My layout looks something like this

```
<LinearLayout>

<Toolbar/>

<Scrollview>

<More views including a edittext in the bottom/>

</Scrollview>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that whenever I select the editext to type something the softkey pushes the edittext up, which is how it's supposed to work but the entire layout is pushed up along with it.. I want to keep the toolbar on the screen, just like how it is in WhatsApp where the toolbar remains on the screen when the edittext is pushed up and down by the softkey.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405993/3395198

Answer (score 0):

just set

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="false">
```

and also add this in your linearlayout

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: hope this helps u!

Comment: do I have to use a coordinator layout?