# ScrollView not scrolling bottom completely

Tags: android, android-scrollview

> Before you mark it duplicate, let me tell you that I have searched for every answer but all in vain.

I am using `Tabs` with `Actionbar`.

I have set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` of `ScrollView` as suggested in many solutions.

I also have removed `android:layout_gravity="center"` from all layouts as suggested by:
[Android scrollview hiding top content in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916317/android-scrollview-hiding-top-content-in-layout)

I also have set `android:fillViewport="true"` but no luck.

Any other hack that I am missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Guest"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </NumberPicker>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_time_slot"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_add_on"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_btn_confirm"/>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is xml of activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.squincy.wspace.ui.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/app_color_black"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_color_black"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/fab"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
        <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @petey sure. check update

Comment: Try adding a layout_marginBottom on your LinearLayout that is the direct child of your ScrollView and see if it adjusts

Comment: @ljpv14 didn't work.

Comment: Are you using an `ActionBar` with `navigationMode` set to `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`? If so, please try to change this to using a `Toolbar` and a `TabLayout` instead as `ActionBar#setNavigationMode` is deprecated.

Comment: @Darwind No navigation mode set.

Comment: But you are using `ActionBar` with `Tabs` like this: `ActionBar.newTab()`? If so, try the layout with a Toolbar instead. I don't have any issues with your code, but I'm not using `Tab`s and the `ActionBar`.
`Tab`s are deprecated.

Comment: Ah I see that you've added the outer layout to your question now. It's a bit hard to figure out what the issue is if you don't add enough info from the beginning.
Are you using `Fragment`s with your `ViewPager` or just views?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should try `NestedScrollView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Just replace your `ScrollView` with this one

I am using it in my app and it works perfectly

Comment: The year is 2023, and this solution fixed my problem. Replacing `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` worked perfectly, even allowing a user to scroll in order to see the list of an `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding paddingBottom to your LinearLayout inside ScrollView.

If that doesn't work then try adding Space as last child of LinearLayout inside ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView
    <LinearLayout
       // other views

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="required_spacing_in_dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView
```