# Actionbar overlapping Scrollbar inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have a scrollview as the root view of a fragment. It's child is a vertical linear layout with 4 elements. The first element is an image. The issue is that the image is getting cut and I can't seem to scroll upwards. This issue is only in landscape mode. Following is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_dark"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/new_form_student"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="15"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/person"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/new_form_person"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="15"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/reason"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/new_form_reason"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="15"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/check"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/new_form_check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="15"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/submit"
        android:id="@+id/new_form_submit"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel"
        android:id="@+id/new_form_cancel"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the screenshot of the issue:
[image: Issue screenshot]

Thanks,

Comment: Having same issue in horizontal wrapped scrollView on linearLayout. Will post an answer if found one, be sure to post solution if you find one too.

Answer (score 1):

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916317/android-scrollview-hiding-top-content-in-layout):

Remove `layout_gravity` attribute from the Linear Layout that is directly placed inside `scrollView`, in your case,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   <!-- android:layout_gravity="center" -->
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

instead of:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```